# Best Side menu option for StoryBoard

Tags: ios7, storyboard

I have started to implement a right side menu on storyboard with autolayout, I am searching I am getting many options like:

https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu

However I am not sure which is best way to accomplish this. What is the best option for a right side menu in my iOS7 app?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. The AMSlideMenu looks pretty decent. Other options are:

**SWRevealViewController**: 
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

**ECSlidingViewController** 
https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController

Alternatively, you could write your own sliding menu. Just depends what you're looking for,

I like the above two options as they also control pan gesture speed - so menu opens / closes at the speed you swipe it.